# Center a form that contains a button in a div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to align a `<form>` to be centered in a `<div>`. This is what I've done till now:

```
<div style="height:auto; margin: 0 auto; align:center;">
  <form style="width:50%; margin:0 auto;" onSubmit="return false;">
  </form>
</div>
```

This centers the form, but is there any other way to do this on a more professional way?

I also have a button in this form which is aligned left by default. I tried to change the alignment but it failed.

Who can help me?

Comment: There are too many meanings of more professional. Do you want the code to look as if a professional done it, or the form to look more professional?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simplest way is to remove the CSS from the HTML and remove the `align:center`.

That way the `button` aligns naturally to the left.

```
div{
    height:auto; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    border:1px solid blue;
}

form{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50%; 
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <form>
      <button></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kCt7k/

---

**EDIT:**

> I need the button to be centered.

Sorry, misread that in the original Q.

In that case, you can use `text-align:center`

```
form{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:50%; 
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/kCt7k/1/

However, this may mess with the other elements in the form.

---

You could just set the `button` as a `block` element and apply margins to it.

```
button{
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**Example 3:** http://jsfiddle.net/kCt7k/2/

Comment: I need the button to be centered.

Comment: that is great, but, I need to have only the button to be centered, not all the form elements.

Comment: You did not mention that `align` is not even a CSS property.

Comment: You're right @Sparky672.  I just told the OP to remove it altogether.

Comment: You have the best (and most complete) answer on this page (+1) but I was surprised nobody else caught it.

Answer (score 1):

> [is] there any other way to be more professional?

```
<div style="height:auto; margin: 0 auto; align:center;">
```

Nobody else mentioned this error, but `align` is not a CSS property.

Perhaps you meant `align` as a `<div>` attribute...

```
<div align="center">
```

However, that's been deprecated, so centering horizontally within a `<div>` would be properly done with `text-align`...

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Being "more professional" might entail moving your style attributes to a separate CSS file. Other than that, this seems like a perfectly reasonable approach.

Would you like me to guess what you did with the button that is wrong?

Comment: but the button is not centered!

Comment: It's not really a perfectly reasonable approach if he's using imaginary CSS properties (`align`).

Comment: @sikas: What do you think I meant with the comment about guessing what you did wrong with the button. You didn't show what you did, so I had no comment about that.

Answer (score 0):

The css is fine, but IMO the "correct" way to do this would be through a separate css file.  Same with the onsubmit that should be through seperate jquery or js.    For the button issue I'd need to see the css from the style sheet and any inline css you are using.   could be any number of reasons that something else is overriding the behavior you want.

One tip with css is if the element isn't behaving correctly, put a 1px solid colored border around it and then you can see where it is being rendered in the browser.  You can then put borders around the other items and see where things are overlapping or pushing an element out of the position you want.